# python obtain the self variable in another class which already has a self function

Tags: python, class, pygame, self

I want to use the self variables in one class and use them in another class which already has its own self variables how to do I do this. Some code here to help.

```
class A():
    self.health = 5
class B(): # This class already has a self function
    for sprite in all_sprites:
        if pygame.sprite.collide_circle(self, sprite):
            self.collide = True
            self.health -= 0.1
```

Comment: What's a "self function" ?

Comment: `self` is a variable for instances to use to refer to themselves.  What is it that your classes represent?

Comment: A function which stores multiple variables so if you call it, it will save you time as you do not have to write all the variables in a parameter of a subroutine, you can just write self.

Comment: One class has health the other wants to deduct health

Comment: You should really strive to produce a workable example. Aim for the code you post to be "copy-pastable" in an interpreter shell. This would help us understand what you are trying to ask. As it stands, I suspect you have some misconceptions regarding OOP. The code you posted would fail with `NameError`, even if we assume you have imported `pygame`.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding.  `self` is only an internal reference.  Within the class, you refer to `self`.  Otherwise, you refer to the `sprite` object directly as such,

```
class A():
    self.health = 5
class B(): # This class already has a self function
    for sprite in all_sprites:
        if pygame.sprite.collide_circle(self, sprite):
            sprite.collide = True
            sprite.health -= 0.1
```

Comment: This would not work either. This would produce a `NameError`.

Comment: You mean because the collide method isn't defined?  I was just trying to copy/paste his original code verbatim.  Or would something else cause it

Comment: No, because `self` doesn't refer to anything in your his/your code. It isn't in a method that has been defined with `self` as the first argument. For example, try typing in class A as it's been defined here.

Comment: Ya, I noticed that too, but dunno what the actual call signature to the pygame method should be.  As you commented above, it's an ill-posed question anyway so probably will end up deleting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code may help to explain how to use `self` in a class. Notice on line 45 that `self` is passed to the `collide` method of the sprite class. Inside of a class, you can pass `self` (which represents the current instance you are working with) to any other instance method or function if desired.

```
import math
import random


def main():
    b = B(5, 5, 2)
    print('Health =', b.health)
    b.collide_sprites()
    print('Health =', b.health)


class Sprite:

    def __init__(self, x, y, radius):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius

    def collide(self, other):
        middle_distance = math.hypot(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)
        edge_margin = self.radius + other.radius
        return middle_distance < edge_margin


class A(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, radius):
        super().__init__(x, y, radius)
        self.health = 5


class B(A):

    def __init__(self, x, y, radius):
        super().__init__(x, y, radius)
        self.all_sprites = [A(
            random.randrange(10),
            random.randrange(10),
            random.randint(1, 4)
        ) for _ in range(50)]
        self.collide = False

    def collide_sprites(self):
        for sprite in self.all_sprites:
            if sprite.collide(self):
                self.collide = True
                self.health -= 0.1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```