# How would I send data from Class A's function to Class B's function if both of them inherit from another class?

Tags: python, tkinter, web-scraping

I am trying to create a simple open-sourced project for tagging Japanese Audiobooks with metadata from Audible Japan. I have a working script that grabs the title, author, and narrators, and I am trying to populate Tkinter's tree with that data. The problem arose when I tried doing it the OOP methodology, and broke everything up into different classes and functions.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class ResultFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)

        # field options
        options = {'padx': 10, 'pady': 10}

        # result label frame
        self.result_label = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text='Results')
        self.result_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W, **options)

        # result tree
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.result_label)
        self.tree['columns'] = ("Title", "Author", "Narrator", "Published")
        self.tree.column("#0", width=0, stretch=NO)  # hide the first autogenerated column
        self.tree.column("Title", anchor=W)
        self.tree.column("Author", anchor=W)
        self.tree.column("Narrator", anchor=W)
        self.tree.column("Published", anchor=W)

        # result tree headings
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='')  # hide the first autogenerated column
        self.tree.heading('Title', text='Title', anchor=W)
        self.tree.heading('Author', text='Author', anchor=W)
        self.tree.heading('Narrator', text='Narrator', anchor=W)
        self.tree.heading('Published', text='Published', anchor=W)

        self.tree.pack()
        self.grid(padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    def populate_tree(self, data):
        count = 0

        for book in data.items():
            self.tree.insert(
                parent='', index='end', iid=count, text='',
                values=(
                    book[0], book[1]['authors'], book[1]['narrators'], 'not implemented'
                )
            )
            count += 1


class SearchFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.audiobooks = {}

        # field options
        options = {'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}

        # search label
        self.search_label = ttk.Label(self, text='Search')
        self.search_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W, **options)

        # search entry
        self.search = tk.StringVar()
        self.search_entry = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.search, width=50)
        self.search_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, **options)
        self.search_entry.focus()

        self.search_button = ttk.Button(self, text="search")
        self.search_button['command'] = self.search_audible
        self.search_button.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tk.W, **options)

        # # results label
        # self.result_label = ttk.Label(self)
        # self.result_label.grid(row=1, columnspan=3, **options)

        # add padding to the frame and show it
        self.grid(padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    def search_audible(self):
        """
        Search audible for the book
        :param self:
        :return:
        """
        temp_authors = []
        temp_narrators = []

        # build the url
        base_url = "https://www.audible.co.jp/search?ipRedirectOverride=true&overrideBaseCountry=true&keywords="
        query = self.search_entry.get()

        # request the page
        page = requests.get(base_url + query)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

        # grab only the content that we need
        search_results = soup.find(id="center-3")

        # scrape information

        for product_item in search_results.find_all('li', class_="bc-list-item productListItem"):
            title = product_item['aria-label']

            # get all of the authors from anchor tags
            for link in soup.find("li", class_="bc-list-item authorLabel").find_all("a"):
                if link.text not in temp_authors:
                    temp_authors.append(link.text)

            # join the results with comma separation to prepare for MP3/M4B file tags
            authors = ", ".join(temp_authors)

            for link in soup.find("li", class_="bc-list-item narratorLabel").find_all("a"):
                if link.text not in temp_narrators:
                    temp_narrators.append(link.text)

            narrators = ", ".join(temp_narrators)

            self.audiobooks[title] = {
                "authors": authors,
                "narrators": narrators
            }

        ResultFrame.populate_tree(self, data=self.audiobooks)


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title('Audiobook Tagger')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    SearchFrame(app)
    ResultFrame(app)
    app.mainloop()
```

From my understanding reading this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41513358, I would essentially have to make ResultFrame inherit from SearchFrame, so it would be `ResultFrame(SearchFrame)` instead of `ResultFrame(ttk.Frame)`. But the issue is that both of my classes are inheriting from `ttk.Frame`, so I am unsure how to proceed.

***To summarize my question, in my `SearchFrame` class, the function called `search_audible` scraped information from Audible. I would like to send that scraped information to `ResultFrame`'s `populate_tree()` so that it can show the results conveniently.***

If possible, I would prefer to have the two Frames into separated classes, because it helps organize and manage the code in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To summarize my question, in my SearchFrame class, the function called
> search_audible scraped information from Audible. I would like to send
> that scraped information to ResultFrame's populate_tree() so that it
> can show the results conveniently.

In order to do that *SearchFrame* needs to be aware of *ResultFrame*.
You can do that by:

```
class SearchFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container,reciever):
        super().__init__(container)
        self.reciever = reciever
```

Through that reference you can target this object by:

```
self.reciever.populate_tree(self, data=self.audiobooks)
```

since you need a reference to that object you need to swap the order of construction to have a reference you can pass:

```
res = ResultFrame(app)
ser = SearchFrame(app,res)
```

---

**Hint**

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.res = ResultFrame(self)
        self.ser = SearchFrame(self,self.res)

        self.title('Audiobook Tagger')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation. It was a lot easier than expected, and I was able to supplement your solution with a tutorial that goes over passing members between classes!